# Brew Fleshcrafting poison limits

Tags: pathfinder-1e, crafting

The feat [Brew Fleshcrafting Poison](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/brew-fleshcrafting-poison-item-creation) states.

> You can create a fleshcrafting poison capable of mimicking one monster ability.

By monster ability does it mean any ability that is listed under the monster's special abilities listing?

A google search lead me [to a forum discussion](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2pced?Brew-Fleshcrafting-Poison) but it didn't really clarify anything for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## A creature brews any fleshgrafting poison at the GM's discretion

The feat [Brew Fleshcrafting Poison](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/brew-fleshcrafting-poison-item-creation) comes from *Endless Night*, the fourth chapter of the [Second Darkness](http://paizo.com/pathfinder/adventurePath/secondDarkness) adventure path for *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* (that's what [OGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Game_License) after the path's entry on the Paizo Web site means). The feat's included on the *d20PFSRD* site, but it's [unavailable](http://paizo.com/search?q=fleshgrafting&what=prd) on Paizo's SRD. Ask the GM whether material that was intended for *D&D 3.5* (which *is* nominally *Pathfinder* compatible) is allowed in the campaign.

If the feat *is* allowed, one should then consult *Endless Night* and its (presumably closed content) descriptions of fleshgrafting poisons: antennae, blinding spittle, burrowing claws, chitinous skin, poison fangs, retractable spines, and stinging tail. (Tip: Some are okay.) One should also keep in mind that as of this writing there have been *no* additional fleshgrafting poisons in any other product.

Those fleshgrafting poisons that *are* described are specific yet don't mention actual creatures (for example, the antennae says, "You sprout antennae from your eye sockets, gaining blindsight out to a range of 30 ft. and normal (human-level) vision" (63) rather than, for example, "You sprout antennae like a [rust monster](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/rustMonster.html)"). Further, each poison has a corresponding *penalty* while the poison's in effect (for example, for the antennae the penalty is −2 hp per HD). (They are, after all, feshcrafting *poisons*.)

In short, trying to divine how to use the feat [Brew Fleshgrafting Poison](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/brew-fleshcrafting-poison-item-creation) solely from the information provided by the *d20PFSRD* is a frustrating and ultimately fruitless exercise.

Thus, for example, were I the GM I would look askance at a player who tried to convince me, as posited by this *Reddit* [thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder_RPG/comments/2im2hj/fleshcrafting_poisons/), that a creature can use the feat [Brew Fleshgrafting Poison](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/brew-fleshcrafting-poison-item-creation) to create a magic item costing 2,000 gp that forever grants the imbiber the [dwoemercat cub](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/dweomercat/dweomercat-cub)'s supernatural ability dweomer leap... especially if the player hadn't consulted the feat's source (which describes in greater detail the effects of chugging a fleshcrafting poison) and argues that there should be no side effect (as each and every printed fleshgrafting poison has one).

In other words, like some other [niche item creation feats](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60019/8610), the player should *first* have the full text of the feat—including the items the game *already* says the creator can create using the feat—*and* know how those items function, *then* the player can consult with the GM about adding new items to the extant list. (Then the creator and the GM can thumb wrestle over pricing by first comparing the new item to similar existing items, as always.)

Answer (score 0):

I would assume based on the wording of the feat that you can use that feat to emulate any Supernatural(Su), Extraordinary(Ex), or Spell-Like(Sp) ability that a monster happens to have in their description through the creation of a potion using a piece of that monster as a catalyst.

This includes but isn't limited to Breath Weapons(Su), Poisons that a creature creates naturally(Ex), or a Chokers Quickness(Su). I would assume that this feat would not however grant spellcasting levels normally given to members of that race, such as the spells a demon, devil, or dragon get just by being members of that race.

I would most definitely talk out this feat with your DM however, as this very same ability to use the special abilities of other creatures is exactly how [Pun-Pun](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Pun-Pun_%283.5e_Optimized_Character_Build%29) got so powerful.

Comment: Seeing that this feat predates the Pathfinder Core Rules, it actually looks like a valid late entry to Pun pun.